# How to detect cars encroaching on the white line of the parking slot from CCTV Camera system?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm developing an application to **identify cars crossing the white line in the parking lot using the CCTV camera system**. I'm experiencing difficulty with some **tilt-angle cameras**.

My solution **for the rear camera angles** is to utilize the shapely library in Python to detect the intersection of the bounding boxes of the car recognized with model yolov7 and the bounding box of the parking slot. The experimental results are pretty promising.
[camera1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8IVA.png)

**In the case of tilt-angle cameras**, such as the one shown below, the car does not cross the line, but its bounding box crosses with the white line. [camera2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHK9W.jpg)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work? Thank you very much.

**Note**: my input is a 1920x1080 video, I use OpenCV to read frames and the yolov7-tiny.pt model to detect cars in the frame. The bounding box of the parking slots is predefined in a JSON file.

**Note2**: I used the yolov7-tiny.pt model in image 1. In image 2, I used yolov7-mask.pt model.

Comment: How do you calculate the bounding box? (What is your input)

Comment: Hi @Ari, my input is a 1920x1080 video, I use OpenCV to read frames and the yolov7-tiny.pt model to detect cars in the frame. The bounding box of the parking slots are predefined in a JSON file. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What is the output of the model a rectangle of the car location? the edges of the car?

Comment: My output is that if the bounding box of a car intersects with the bounding box of the parking slot, I'll show the warning on my dashboard.  I have trouble with the tilt-angle cameras when in reality the car doesn't hit the line but its bounding box does. (the red line in image camera2 above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `yolov7-tiny.pt` model gives you back not only the bounding box of the car but also the car edges, as seen in the second image.

```
p = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True) # cnt is the x,y values of the car's edges
appr = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*p, True)
```

The `appr` contains the bousing box of the car aligned with the car angle.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, that's what I'm looking for. Side note: in image 2 above, I used yolov7-mask.pt instead of yolov7-tiny.pt model.